# Modify CSS class "two" if class "one" is not shown on screen

Tags: css

I use Php to set the CSS class of element "one" to `display : none` under certain conditions.

Is there a way, **using CSS only**, to change the color of class "two" if class "one" is not shown on screen (`display : none` is active, set by Php)?

I know how to do this using php, javascript, etc, I am just wondering if there is a CSS-only alternative...

Thank you!

Comment: Basically, if your presentation involves an 'if,' your presentation layer will require JavaScript or a server-side script to deal with it. CSS has no capacity for conditionals (currently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to change the color of class "two" if class "one" is not shown on screen

That's not possible using CSS only. CSS got no conditions, just styling.